# oracle forms 6i - When validate trigger on item - cursor do not move

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have created a form sales and put validate trigger on `clientid`/`customerid`

```
if sales_receivedamt > 0 
then 
message('You cant change it');
raise form_trigger_failure
end if;
```

Example:

Suppose through execute query, sales no `605` where `client_id=700` and `sales_receivedamt>0`. When the user is trying to change/update `client_id` from `700` to `701` but system give message alert.
then user enter previous `client_id=700` but still message alert is showing even `client_id` property required is set "No".

Comment: Which "message alert is showing"? How is code you posted (that's a WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger, right?) related to a fact that CLIENT_ID "required" property is set to "No"? These are two different things. In my opinion, you should explain the problem a lot better. Attach the screenshot to illustrate it.

Comment: Sure.. I have developed a sales form where user entered a record (saleno 15) with client_id is 10. A list of values LOV and validation trigger is imposed on client_id field where required is set "No". The user execute the record/saleno 15 and try to change the client_id from 10 to 11 then validate trigger show alert message based on validation condition... then user reset client_id=10 but inspite message is showing.... I m hopeful that now it is clear enough ... otherwise share ur whatsapp mine is 923005557798